# Cordova iOS Plugins Failed Issue when we launching the app in Xcode

Tags: ionic3, ionic4, phonegap

I have a Cordova 5.0[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iA5VF.png).0 project, and I'm testing using the X-Code emulator

I get the following errors when launching the app in XCode:

**FAILED pluginJSON = ["AuthProxy1342781311","AuthProxy","initWebStrategies",[]]
2020-01-24 12:59:00.432213+0530 myJobCard[23188:330651] ERROR: Plugin 'StatusBar' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.
2020-01-24 12:59:00.432347+0530  FAILED pluginJSON = ["StatusBar1342781312","StatusBar","_ready",[]]
2020-01-24 12:59:00.432539+0530  ERROR: Plugin 'Console' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.
2020-01-24 12:59:00.432642+0530  FAILED pluginJSON = ["INVALID","Console","logLevel",["LOG","Set javascript initial log level: ERROR"]]
2020-01-24 12:59:00.432821+0530  ERROR: Plugin 'Console' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.
2020-01-24 12:59:00.432906+0530  FAILED pluginJSON = ["INVALID","Console","logLevel",["LOG","Ionic Native: deviceready event fired after 444 ms"]]
2020-01-24 12:59:00.433063+0530  ERROR: Plugin 'SMPSettingsExchangePlugin' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.
2020-01-24 12:59:00.433132+0530  FAILED pluginJSON = ["SMPSettingsExchangePlugin1342781313","SMPSettingsExchangePlugin","disableDataLink",[]]
2020-01-24 12:59:00.433319+0530  ERROR: Plugin 'StatusBar' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.
2020-01-24 12:59:00.433385+0530  FAILED pluginJSON = ["INVALID","StatusBar","styleDefault",[]]
2020-01-24 12:59:00.433545+0530  ERROR: Plugin 'SplashScreen' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.
2020-01-24 12:59:00.433613+0530 myJobCard[23188:330651] FAILED pluginJSON = ["INVALID","SplashScreen","hide",[]]**

We are Trying below solutions.

**1) In X Code, goto Build Phases -> open the Compiled Sources dropdown. Click + and add the missing plugin .m file .**

**2)i. delete ./plugins/ios.json, ii. then delete ./platforms/ios, iii. then run cordova platform add ios iv. then cordova build. Deleting ios.json**

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
rm -rf node_modules
ionic cordova platform rm ios
npm install
ionic cordova platform add ios
ionic cordova build ios (with dev team pre-selected)
```

Select project name, not pods > select device / emulator >
Build

Comment: Thanks for the giving replay we are trying the that solution also I am getting the same issue
ERROR: Plugin 'AuthProxy' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.
2020-01-27 12:41:01.364336+0530  FAILED pluginJSON = ["AuthProxy602025675","AuthProxy","initWebStrategies",[]]
2020-01-27 12:41:01.364491+0530  ERROR: Plugin 'StatusBar' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.